# How to create an array storing PictureBox names in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, picturebox

I want to create an array of picturebox names, which I will later use in a FOREACH loop and do a certain thing to each picturebox instead of having to write the code for all of the pictureboxes separately. In another solution the code below worked, but here it only returns an error: "A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'Puzzle.Form1.pic1'"

I could not find what I was looking for on the internet, even though I tried to write it in different ways. Thanks!

```
    //Define an array and place the 9 picture boxes in it

    //System.Drawing. [] PictureBox = {}
    //PictureBox[] Pictures1 = new PictureBox[9];
    //PictureBox[] Pictures1 = { pic1, pic2 };
    //PictureBox pBoxes = new PictureBox[] {pic1, pic2, pic3};

    PictureBox[] diceloc = { pic1, pic2, pic3, pic4, pic5, pic6, pic7, pic8, pic9 };
```

Comment: do you use this code inside a static method???

Comment: You have to study very basics of C# first, before asking any further question (looking at your attempts).

Comment: There is not much you (or any newbie) can or should do with the names, which are basically strings. You need to use references!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a new instance of the PictureBox class before you can set its values.

```
PictureBox[] diceloc = new PictureBox[] {pic1, pic2, pic3, pic4};
```

Comment: Thanks! It still didn't work, but then I moved the whole code to within "public Form1()" instead of "public partial class Form1 : Form" and it's working